# Is it possible for page to get your installed extensions through javascript?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, browser-extensions

When you visit a page, could that page tell what extensions you are running
if javascript is enabled?
If so then could we stop them or at least make it extremely difficult to increase our privacy?

Comment: Most of the assets related with a Chrome extension are treated as having a unique origin. JavaScript on the page can’t retrieve them due to Same-Origin Policy. However - many extensions modify the DOM, and iirc there’s nothing preventing the site from identifying and fingerprinting those manipulations.

Comment: What are DOM and IIRC?

Comment: Document object model (DOM) and if I recall correctly (iirc), respectively.

Comment: E.g. there are several ways how you could detect *NoScript*. If JS is completely deactivated, then user will enter `<noscript></noscript>` tag (if there is any) or will just not request your *JS* file. If *JS* is allowed on that domain, then you could trigger *XSS*-like request and check if it gets blocked. But here you have to be careful, because you have to distinguish anti-XSS mechanisms between no-XSS-extensions and browsers, e.g. **google chrome's XSS auditor** VS **NoScript's XSS filter**. I think you take like top 50 extensions and just check make very specific check for each of them.

Comment: I mean I searched already how to detect it. At least it is not so easy on modern desktop browsers. I don't know about mobile browsers. Desktop browsers are obviously protecting their extensions. That would be a security hole if one would allow to show browsers extensions to everyone. I mean there is a difference e.g. if you are using *anti-WebRtc* extension or not, if you're using *uMatrix* or you have no *XSS&Co* protection at all. Because I would consider it as *client-side information leak*.

Comment: You need to check how those extensions work and how you can fingerprint them, so you need to check how do they behave on certain features you might have added to your website. So if user disables all *JS*, you might detect it. But I think there is no general solution and in some cases you won't be able to detect all extensions.

Comment: for moderators: This is not an answer, because it doesn't say anything, it is just a suggestion based on my experience with that topic. I searched already for that and ended up with this - extension fingerprinting. But I don't know if there is another way.

Comment: https://amiunique.org/tools + "My fingerprint". It seems to detect several browser extensions.

Answer (score 1):

If the site can control the extension, yes. Look at [`chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external).

If the site can't control the extension, no. Chrome protects the extensions.

But there are ways.

1. If the extension has `web_accessible_resources`, the javascript of the website can XHR or whatever to the resource (e.g. `chrome-extension://oiplkfaidhjklglajdpfehoagkmlcakh/images/camera.png` for [Pig Toolbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pig-toolbox-super-gesture/oiplkfaidhjklglajdpfehoagkmlcakh/)) and check the reply.
2. If the extension modifies DOM, the site can detect it using Javascript.

If it is not an extension but an app, the site can just use [`chrome.app.isInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-app-24)

If the extension wants to check other extension, it can use [`chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external)

Comment: I imagine there are a number of fingerprinting methods they can use as well.